# Applescript move each file to its new folder

Tags: automation, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

I have over 200 pictures. I want applescript to:

1. create new folder for each of this 200 pictures based on name of file
2. move the file into it

so ie. XXX.jpg gets into XXX folder.

the task is more or less simple yet all aplescript code s i found on mac forums were outdated.
i am on latest version of mountain lion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set myFolder to (choose folder)
tell application "Finder" to set myFiles to files of myFolder as alias list

repeat with aFile in myFiles
    set bName to my baseName(aFile)
    tell application "Finder"
        set folderExists to exists folder bName of myFolder
        if not folderExists then make new folder at myFolder with properties {name:bName}
        move aFile to folder bName of myFolder
    end tell
end repeat

on baseName(myFile)
    tell application "System Events" to set {fileName, fileExt} to {name, name extension} of myFile
    return text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & fileExt in fileName) - 1) of fileName
end baseName
```

EDIT

```
set myFolder to findFolder()

tell application "Finder" to set myFiles to files of myFolder as alias list

repeat with aFile in myFiles
    set bName to my baseName(aFile)
    tell application "Finder"
        set folderExists to exists folder bName of myFolder
        if not folderExists then make new folder at myFolder with properties {name:bName}
        move aFile to folder bName of myFolder
    end tell
end repeat

---------------- HANDLERS ----------------
on baseName(myFile)
    tell application "System Events" to set {fileName, fileExt} to {name, name extension} of myFile
    return text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & fileExt in fileName) - 1) of fileName
end baseName


on findFolder()
    activate application "SystemUIServer"
    -- Bug pointed out by Lauri Ranta http://www.openradar.me/9406282
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        set mySelection to (get selection)
        if mySelection ≠ {} then
            set mySelection to first item of (get selection)
            if mySelection's class = folder then
                set currentFolder to mySelection
            else if mySelection's class = document file then
                set currentFolder to parent of mySelection
            else if mySelection's class = alias file then
                set currentFolder to original item of mySelection
            end if
        else
            set currentFolder to target of front Finder window
        end if
    end tell
    return (currentFolder as alias)
end findFolder
```

Comment: thanx. possible to mid it in a way that 'my folder' is what finder shows up? aka i open folder i nfinder, and thats the folder where the work should go. would be more generic then